# What's the best way to use username/password auth in a Ruby script in OS X?

Tags: macos, authentication, scripting, passwords

I am working on an automated backup script. This script needs to download an HTTP resource using a username and password. At the moment, the auth credentials are in cleartext, which is obviously not ideal from a security point of view. I recently discovered the `security` utility on OS X after reading [this](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/01/16/keychain_cli/) blog post. `security` gives you keychain access from the command line. The OS X Keychain allows you to specify applications that are allowed access to a specific password, but it turns out that you can't give `myscript` access if it in turns calls `security`, you have to put `security`, which basically gives access to anyone on the machine.

Aside from creating a user (e.g. "backups") purely for running this script, and giving the script 700 permissions, are there any better ways to solve this problem in OS X 10.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, anything you store in a way accessible to your program with no user input can be accessed by a determined user. If I were you, I'd just store the credentials in a `0700`-permissions file to ensure that only the right people can see it.

If you're wondering why not to obfuscate the passwords, you might want to take a look at Pidgin's policy on the matter:[Plain Text Passwords](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/PlainTextPasswords).